# Чому бажають багато племінників?

Tags: фразеологізми

Чому в деяких привітаннях з днем народженням бажають саме багато племінників? Наприклад,

> Щастя, здоровля, багато племінників!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Відео з фразою з запитання - [Щастя, здоровля, багато племінників!](https://youtu.be/-KFIxCxPgrA?t=27)

Уривок з діалогу тамади і брата нареченого або нареченої:

> Брат: *Бажаю вам щастя, здоров'я, ну, і багато вам племінників.*
>   Тамада: *Для тебе племінників, багато діточок мається на увазі.*

Хлопчина просто хвилювався і помилився сказавжи  "племінників", замість "діточок".

Ще хоча б одне вітання серйозне з такою фразою я не знайшла.

Comment: Тобто це обмовочка (помилка на слові), яка потім стала мемом — я правильно розумію?

Comment: @Sasha саме так.